# How would I get an MP3 file from a website without buying the album?

Tags: web, download, mp3

I've been searching for a album that mysteriously just disappeared from the internet a while ago and I finally found it. The problem is I wish to download the songs on the website but have no idea how to as the only other way is to pay and I really don't have any money. Any help possible? The link to the website is: https://shipwrek.bandcamp.com/album/teacup-in-a-tempest

Answer (score 1):

It is a name your price, Click Buy digital album and enter 0 as the price. Then click download to your computer.

Comment: Although question is somehow on topic, the response is not really.